# @State property value is not retain when called within the sheet(item:) method

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, I have an optional `@State` variable call `isReseting` which I set to `true` with a tap of a button. The button also triggers a sheet when it's tapped, which is working fine but what doesn't work is that if I read the value of the `isResting` variable inside the `.sheet` it outputs as `nil` and I'm expecting that to be `true` since it was set to `true` when the button was tapped.

Any idea why the value of the `isReseting` variable becomes `nil` inside the `.sheet`?

```
struct Item: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var active:Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items:[Item] = [Item(name: "Oranges", active: true),
                    Item(name: "Apples", active: false),
                    Item(name: "Cookies", active: false) ]
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    @State private var isReseting: Bool?
        
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(items){ item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.name)
                    
                    Button(item.active ? "Reset": "Initiate"){
                        selectedItem = item
                        isReseting = true
                        let _ = print("Value after button tap: \(isReseting)")// output: Value after button tap: Optional(true)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(item.active ? Color.blue: Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 65)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem){ item in
            // I'm expecting isReseting to be true here, but it's nil
            let _ = print("Value in sheet: \(isReseting)")// outputs: Value in sheet: nil
            
            if isReseting == true {
                Text("It's reseting!!!")
            }else{
                Text("It's NOT reseting")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if you make it a straight `Bool`, instead of an `Optional` it still give you "false" in the sheet's closure which is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting caught by the fact that `sheet(item:)` *only* re-renders based on `item` -- not the encapsulating View's `@State` variables. As long as you explicitly pass `isReseting` through the `item`, it will work:

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var active:Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items:[Item] = [Item(name: "Oranges", active: true),
                    Item(name: "Apples", active: false),
                    Item(name: "Cookies", active: false) ]
    
    struct SheetItem : Identifiable {
        var item: Item
        var isReseting: Bool
        
        var id: UUID {
            self.item.id
        }
    }
    
    @State private var selectedItem: SheetItem?
    @State private var isReseting: Bool?
        
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(items){ item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.name)
                    
                    Button(item.active ? "Reset": "Initiate"){
                        isReseting = true
                        selectedItem = SheetItem(item: item, isReseting: isReseting ?? false)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(item.active ? Color.blue: Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 65)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
            let _ = print("Value in sheet: \(item.isReseting)")
            
            if item.isReseting == true {
                Text("It's reseting!!!")
            } else {
                Text("It's NOT reseting")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A second way to accomplish this is explicitly pass a `Binding` (even though you don't need to mutate it in the sheet), since it will maintain its link to the `@State` variable:

```
struct Item: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var active:Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items:[Item] = [Item(name: "Oranges", active: true),
                    Item(name: "Apples", active: false),
                    Item(name: "Cookies", active: false) ]
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    @State private var isReseting: Bool?
        
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(items){ item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.name)
                    
                    Button(item.active ? "Reset": "Initiate"){
                        selectedItem = item
                        isReseting = true
                        let _ = print("Value after button tap: \(isReseting)")// output: Value after button tap: Optional(true)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(item.active ? Color.blue: Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 65)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem){ item in
            // I'm expecting isReseting to be true here, but it's nil
            SheetView(isReseting: $isReseting)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView : View {
    @Binding var isReseting : Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("Value in sheet: \(isReseting)")// outputs: Value in sheet: nil
        
        if isReseting == true {
            Text("It's reseting!!!")
        }else{
            Text("It's NOT reseting")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you for pointing the fact that `sheet(item:)` only rerenders based on `item` and not the `@State` variable.